# How to change the id's of classes with values given in array

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a code in which there is `6 classes` with names `item1` to `item6`, these classes have id's have `id's 1 to 6`..

i `want to change the id of these classes` with values given in `array newids`..

i have tried the code

> y[i].id += newids[i-1];

but it is giving me the error
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined..

**How to change the id of classes item1 to item6 with newids given in array**..

How do i achieve this?

```js
var newids=[2,1,5,4,6,3];
console.log(newids);

for(i=1;i<=6;i++)
{
var y="item"+i;
x = document.getElementsByClassName(y);
console.log(x);

 y[i].id += newids[i-1];
}
```

```css
.item1{
 border:2px solid black;
    float:left;
 position:fixed;
 width:5vw;
 height:5vh;
}
.item2{
 border:2px solid black;
 float:left;

 width:5vw;
 height:5vh;
 margin-left:6%;

 } 
.item3{
 border:2px solid black;
 float:left;
 width:5vw;
 height:5vh;
 margin-left:1%;

}  
.item4{
 border:2px solid black;
    float:left;
 width:5vw;
 height:5vh;
 margin-left:1%;

} 
.item5{
 border:2px solid black;
    float:left;
 width:5vw;
 height:5vh;
 margin-left:1%;
}
.item6{
 border:2px solid black;
    float:left;
 width:5vw;
 height:5vh;
 margin-left:1%;
 }

h2{
text-align:center;
margin-top:0%;}
```

```html
<div class="item1" id="1">
 <h2>1</h2>
</div>
<div class="item2" id="2">
 <h2>2</h2>
</div>
<div class="item3" id="3">
 <h2>3</h2>
</div>
<div class="item4" id="4">
 <h2>4</h2>
</div>
<div class="item5" id="5">
 <h2>5</h2>
</div>
<div class="item6" id="6">
 <h2>6</h2>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've almost got it right, you just need to change two things:

1. `x = document.getElementsByClassName(y)` returns a [HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection), thus you need to get the first element in this collection using index 0: 
   `x = document.getElementsByClassName(y)[0]`.
2. Change `y.id += newids[i];` to `x.id = newids[i];` as `x` is your element which you want to change the id of, not the string `y`. Also to set (not append) to the id you need to use a single equals (with no `+`).

See working example below (inspect element to see the new ids):

```js
var newids = [2, 1, 5, 4, 6, 3];

for (i = 1; i <= 6; i++) {
  var y = "item" + i;
  x = document.getElementsByClassName(y)[0];

  x.id = newids[i - 1];
}
```

```css
.item1 {
  border: 2px solid black;
  float: left;
  position: fixed;
  width: 5vw;
  height: 5vh;
}

.item2 {
  border: 2px solid black;
  float: left;
  width: 5vw;
  height: 5vh;
  margin-left: 6%;
}

.item3 {
  border: 2px solid black;
  float: left;
  width: 5vw;
  height: 5vh;
  margin-left: 1%;
}

.item4 {
  border: 2px solid black;
  float: left;
  width: 5vw;
  height: 5vh;
  margin-left: 1%;
}

.item5 {
  border: 2px solid black;
  float: left;
  width: 5vw;
  height: 5vh;
  margin-left: 1%;
}

.item6 {
  border: 2px solid black;
  float: left;
  width: 5vw;
  height: 5vh;
  margin-left: 1%;
}

h2 {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 0%;
}
```

```html
<div class="item1" id="1">
  <h2>1</h2>
</div>
<div class="item2" id="2">
  <h2>2</h2>
</div>
<div class="item3" id="3">
  <h2>3</h2>
</div>
<div class="item4" id="4">
  <h2>4</h2>
</div>
<div class="item5" id="5">
  <h2>5</h2>
</div>
<div class="item6" id="6">
  <h2>6</h2>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just an alternative:

```
var newids=[2,1,5,4,6,3];
for(i=1;i<=6;i++) {
  var y="item"+i;
  $("." + y).attr("id", newids[i-1]);
}
```

You don't need `x = document.getElementsByClassName(y)` at all, because you already got the class you want to update.